# Windows Phone 7 TopProperty Changed event

Tags: windows-phone-7, dependency-properties

I want to do some code after Canvas.topProperty is changed in my control.

I've seen examples with DependencyPropertyDescriptor but Visual studio do not recognize this class in Windows Phone 7 project.

How can I manage this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to look at is the LayoutUpdated event handler for the canvas.

First of all you need to store the value of the top margin in a separate field/property.

```
double top = 0;
top = YourCanvas.Margin.Top;
```

Then, in the LayoutUpdated event handler you can check whether the margin was modified:

```
void LayoutRoot_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (LayoutRoot.Margin.Top != top)
    {
        // Your action here
        Debug.WriteLine("CHANGED!");
    }
}
```